# Angular 2 RC1 component routing doesn't load anything

Tags: angular, angularjs-routing

I am using Angular 2.0.0-rc.1. I have tried to setup routing with a single route to start with, but nothing is being displayed. No errors are being thrown.

Main.ts

```
import { bootstrap }    from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ROUTER_PROVIDERS } from '@angular/router';

bootstrap(AppComponent, [
  ROUTER_PROVIDERS
]);
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MyComponent} from './my/my.component';
import { HTTP_PROVIDERS } from '@angular/http';
import { ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import 'rxjs/Rx';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: 'app/app.component.html',
  directives: [MyComponent, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
  providers: [HTTP_PROVIDERS]
})

@Routes([
  { path: '/', component: MyComponent }
])

export class AppComponent { }
```

app.component.html

```
<div>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

index.html starts with

```
<html>
<head>
  <base href="/">
```

MyComponent

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'pr-my',
    templateUrl: 'app/my/my.component.html'
})

export class MyComponent {
}
```

UPDATE:
If I add a routerLink into app.component.html and click it, the contents loads as expected. It doesn't load without clicking the link.

```
<a [routerLink]="['/']">Home</a>
```

Comment: Do you get any error in console?

Comment: The MyComponent in the directives is redundant

Comment: @micronyks - No errors in the console

Comment: The routerLink is another workaround to the one mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to inject the router

```
class AppComponent {
  constructor(router:Router){}
}
```

This is a known issue.

Comment: Glad it helped. If you have a routerLink in AppComponent you don't need to inject the router. I just find injecting the router less ugly than adding a routerLink and then making it invisible (if I actually don't need it). You might be better off sticking with router-deprecated for now. They are now again reconsidering how they move foreard with the router story.